# Get HTML data using Rxjs Ajax

Tags: ajax, rxjs

I have an HTML containing a form, now I want to load that form and replace it in the DIV using RxjS (which I already use to consume the data from the API)

For this look for and adapt the following code:

```
    const users = ajax({
        url: '/form.action',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: "inline=1",
    }).pipe(
        map(response => console.log('response: ', response)),
        catchError(error => {
            console.log('error: ', error);
            return of(error);
        })
    );
```

but it returns the response to null and the responseType says JSON, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that you are using the `map` operator, but not returning a value, so you are essentially mapping it to `undefined`. Instead of`map` use `tap` which does not modify the emitted value.

Comment: then i replace the map by tag, i need to suscribe it or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i change the code adding the response and its working now, the code goes:

```
    ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: link + '?inline=1',
        responseType: 'text'
    }).pipe(
        map((response) => {
            return response.response;
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            return of(error);
        })
    ).subscribe({
        next: value => {
            jQuery('main').html(value);
        },
        error: err => {
            console.log(err)
        },
        complete: () => {
            console.log("loaded")
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using `map` as per your first attempt is indeed the best way to start, so that `users` can be kept a "pure" observable stream without side effects.

Then, as you also noted, you need to subscribe to it. It's great practice to keep observables and subscriptions somewhat separate in code.

If you are creating some jQuery templates, you may want to just use [Rimmel.js](https://github.com/hellomenu/rimmel), which helps you keep a leaner code by seamlessly subscribing to your observables and sinking whatever they emit right into the DOM, so you don't have to:

```
  const users = ajax.getJSON(`${link}?inline=1`).pipe(
      map(response => response.response),
      catchError(error => of(error)),
    );
  
  jQuery('#main').html(render`
    <h1>Results</h1>
    <div>
      ${users}
    </div>
  `);
```

Inspired by https://codepen.io/fourtyeighthours/pen/rNqzgdq